# How does Redis run lua script?

Tags: lua, redis

```
local a = {}

for i,v in ipairs(KEYS) do
    a[i] = redis.call('hgetall',v)
end

return a
```

**Above is my script**

```
eval test.lua 3 user:1 user:2 user:3 0  
(error) ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:2: '=' expected near 'end'
```

**Above is my redis command and error**
Can anyone tell why the error happened and show me how to write a correct command?

Answer (score 3):

The [`EVAL` command] (https://redis.io/commands/eval) expects the first argument to be the actual script, not a filename. Fix that and it should work.